# Database activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB\lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked

Tags: tomcat6

I have the following problem:
I have a web application that invokes a war that contains a jms and each application has its own file context.xml.
Both applications run on Tomcat 6
At a time when the web application invokes the application that contains the jms I get the following error message:

Database activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB\lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: File 'activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB\lock' could not be locked.

If I stop the application server that acts as jms, the error message disappears.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is set up two message brokers that point to the same location on disk, and thereby accidentally set up [shared-storage master-slave](https://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html). One broker in the first app will start up fine, while the other will wait until the first one goes down. The usual way to deal with this is to run ActiveMQ outside of Tomcat, and have your applications connect to that.